# making dropdown for m the database

Tags: php, smarty

hello friends 
that time i want to make a function like
i want to make a dropdown menu from the data base EX
from the dorp down 1car
                   2 ball
                   3 bat ets all these things are fetching from the database

help me

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of making a dropdown with Smarty:

In the PHP file:

```
$array = array('apple', 'orange');
$smarty->assign('items', $array);
```

In the Smarty template:

```
<select>
{foreach from=$items item=item}
<option>{$item}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```